# Google Colab - how to conditionally stop execution of current cell?

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Google Colab, is there a way to, in code, conditionally stop (i.e. jump out of) execution of the current cell?

Note, I'm not asking how to shutdown or disconnect the entire notebook/kernel, I'd just like a command that, when invoked, will not execute any more of the code in that cell only.

In a regular Python program I usually use `quit()` to exit the program, so I hoped this would work in Colab:

```
for i in range(10000):
    # only print the first 10 numbers
    if i > 10:
        quit()   # what should go here ?? this line does not work as expected
    # end if

    print(i)
```

But the `quit()` is ineffective.  I've also tried other things in the same location, for example `sys.exit()` as recommended by ChatGPT, but then I get this error message:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.

SystemExit
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:3561: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)
```

I should mention that I realize in this very simplified case I could simply replace `quit()` with `break`, but in more complicated situations (for example multiple nested loops) that won't work without sprinkling in multiple breaks, and I'm really looking for a single line that will jump out of the cell's execution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I once used the raise statement with the KeyboardInterrupt exception to conditionally stop the execution of the current cell. For your codes, I guess you can try this:

```
for i in range(10000):
    # only print the first 10 numbers
    if i > 10:
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I would prefer an option where I don't have to cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an if statement to pass the current cell. it also mean skipping the cell.

```
if i>10:
   break
```

For another case, you can check if a variable is NoneType to skip the cell to prevent the error and notebook will continue with the next launched cells.

```
if type(var) == type(None):
   pass
else:
   # your code
```